# Does March of the Machines make artifacts in hand creatures as well?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I looked over the Gatherer rulings and it didn't mention anything about it, nor does it mention permanents on the card or in the rulings.

I ask because I wanted to know if I could use [Æther Vial](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=%C3%86ther%20Vial) to summon any artifact from my hand with [March of the Machines](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=March%20of%20the%20Machines) in play.

Comment: As an addendum, I would recommend using the Comprehensive rules as your guide to any rules based questions you might have - it's a huge document, but it's all in there.  http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20121001.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On any given card, a card that specifies a permanent type without explicitly saying 'card' only affects permanents in play (unless otherwise specified by the card).  If you have an artifact card in your hand, it is exactly that - an artifact card, and not an 'artifact'...

Relevant rule

> **109.2.** If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

(https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Object)

Comment: Also, note that this means that (normally non-creature) artifacts played from your hand will be artifact spells but not creature spells, and cannot be countered by cards like Essence Scatter.